Aquaman and Submariner
Although competitors, Marvel and DC have published the occasional crossover (In addition to two 'Batman meets Punisher' works I have also heard of a work where Superman fought the Hulk). However, each company has their own version of the 'undersea prince of Atlantis' (specifically Marvel's Prince Namor the Submariner and DC's Aquaman)- If characters from both Marvel and DC continuities can interact this way, how do they reconcile there being two rulers of Atlantis?

There could be more than one place called Atlantis.

@Paulie_D - Atlantis, TX

London UK, London, Ontario.... for that matter, Ontario CA

https://screenrant.com/namor-vs-aquaman-atlantis-jla-avengers-crossover/ - in short they exist in difference universes. There's two different Atlantises

↑ Yes, there's more than one continuity/multiverse, just like there's more than one Earth in Marvel.

Back thru the Silver Age, DC itself had (at least) a pair of Atlantises. One where Lori Lemaris and the merpeople lived and the one with Aquaman.

In the earlier DC/Marvel crossovers, such as Superman vs. The Amazing Spider-Man (January, 1976) and Punisher/Batman: Deadly Knights (October, 1994), the titular characters were presented as existing within the same universe, and the question of how Namor and Aquaman could both be ruler of Atlantis was never addressed, as those characters weren't referenced in those crossovers.
Starting with Green Lantern / Silver Surfer: Unholy Alliance (January, 1995), though, DC and Marvel characters were presented as existing in separate universes, and this became the norm from that point forward.

SILVER SURFER: You are Hal Jordan, called Parallax? I have travelled widely in this universe. Why have I never heard of you?
HAL JORDAN: Because I am not from this universe. I come from what you would consider another reality.

Green Lantern / Silver Surfer: Unholy Alliances (January, 1995)

Namor and Aquaman first interacted in Marvel Versus DC #2 (March, 1996), which was a direct follow-up to the events of Green Lantern / Silver Surfer: Unholy Alliance.


Marvel Versus DC #2 (March, 1996)


They did backslide at least bit after that,; I remember was Spider-Man / Batman (Sept '95) and its sequel Batman / Spider-Man (Oct '97), both of which take place in an apparent shared universe. The former was even referenced in the Marvel Versus DC crossover, for maximum confusion.

@notovny - The latter was also referenced in Unlimited Access, a sequel to DC Versus Marvel. DC Versus Marvel introduced the concept that the DC and Marvel Earths could partially or fully merge under certain conditions, so my headcanon is that the Batman/Spider-Man crossovers took place while something like that was in effect. That said, I doubt the actual writers put that much thought into it.
